# How to enable syntax highlighting on vim before 7.3?

Tags: vim

For some reason (experiment on the research work in a 2006 paper) I need to use Ubuntu 8.04, which only has vim 7.1.x in its default package source. `syntax on` and `filetype on` are not supported in this version of vim. Manuals regarding `syntax` I can search are for vim 7.3. Are there alternative ways to enable syntax highlighting on older versions of VIM? Was syntax highlighting feature introduced that late?

Comment: You can consider building Vim from source.

Comment: Could you copy the relevant files to a more modern system?  Or set up NFS on the 8.04 system and edit them remotely?